# Need Help To Uncheck Radio Button If Aleady Checked Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

i need help to uncheck or check same radio button if button already checked? I have jquery function which is used to enable or disabled other radio buttons if already checked now i want to add some function that use for check or uncheck same radio button?

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio').click(function(){
      var $inputs = $('input:radio')

      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true);
      }else{
        $inputs.prop('disabled',false); 
      }
    })

  });
})(jQuery);

<input type="radio" value="Test1" />Test1
<input type="radio" value="Test2" />Test2
<input type="radio" value="Test1" />Test1
<input type="radio" value="Test2" />Test2
```

Comment: What's the use case behind this? Do you maybe just want to reset the radio buttons' state everytime the page is shown?

Answer (score 5):

Although it is too late to answer, it could help others
I tried this solution.
Works very well for me!

```
$("input[type='radio'].myClass").click(function(){
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($self.attr('checkstate') == 'true')
        {
            $self.prop('checked', false);
            $self.each( function() {
                $self.attr('checkstate', 'false');
            })  
        }
        else
        {
            $self.prop('checked', true);
            $self.attr('checkstate', 'true');
            $("input[type='radio'].myClass:not(:checked)").attr('checkstate', 'false');
        }
})
```

Comment: It's never too late! Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace `disabled` with `checked`:

```
$input.prop("checked", false);
```

or for `this` element:

```
this.checked = false;
```

However, if you are looking for form element which can be checked and unchecked, maybe `input type="checkbox" />` is what you need.

Comment: do you mean by this one line `if($(this).is(':checked'))`

Comment: So by the logic, you should use something like `this.checked = !this.checked`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$inputs.filter(':checked').prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need checkbox instead of radio button to uncheck the checked :

```
<input class="checkDisable" type="checkbox" value="Test1" />Test1
<input class="checkDisable" type="checkbox" value="Test2" />Test2
<input class="checkDisable" type="checkbox" value="Test3" />Test3
<input class="checkDisable" type="checkbox" value="Test4" />Test4


(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('input:checkbox.checkDisable').change(function(){
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox.checkDisable')
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true);
    }else{
        $inputs.prop('disabled',false); 
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
    }
 })

});
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Mohamed Ali i have already other checkboxes in my page so if i will use again checkbox with the jquery then problem will create

Comment: @edgematrix it is so simple add class name for your specified checkbox then select the checkboxes with this class

Answer (score 0):

The [answer of Pablo Araya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52602175/2359227) is good, but ...

```
$self.prop('checked', true);
```

is superfluous here. The radio button already has a checked state for every click.